# How to load the html file into the iframe after uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I tried to make uploading html file, when I upload my want his displays in the iframe or object.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="file" /> 
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Load File" /> 
</form>
<object width="1225" height="1000" data="'file here'"></object>
```

**accept-file.php**

```
if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])
{
    $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
    $allowedExts = array("php", "html");
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
    if($_FILES['file']['type'] !== 'text/html') 
    {
        $valid_file = false;
        $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s not supported.';
        echo $message ;
    }
    else
    {
        $currentdir = getcwd();
        $target = $currentdir .'/uploads/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $data = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);       
        $contents = file_get_contents($target);
        echo $contents;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can echo it directly in an `<iframe>` after the HTML File has been uploaded:

```
echo '<iframe src="' . $target . '"></iframe>';
```

`$target` will be the path to the HTML File.

Comment: Thanks @luweiqi, where I need to add $target

Comment: @Duwiirwanto You already specified `$target` --> `$target = $currentdir .'/uploads/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: result The address wasn't understood,

Comment: @Duwiirwanto You'll need to know the path, I'm not sure where do you store the HTML file, try echoing out `$target` to check

Comment: nice work i change $currentdir using my path ip addres

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="/upload/Uploaded_file.html" > </iframe>
```

If you store full path in database than replace "src" content  with  you database value.

Comment: thanks.. @viral Pathak. I did not save it into the database , simply save the data to a .html file uploads

Comment: ok, than retrive HTML file name and replace  with SRC. like if you have uploaded HTML file name  is , about.html  than replace  uploaded_file.html.. Please Give proper path of  that html page